# Responsive image not working on android phone/chrome browser

Tags: android, css, html, google-chrome, firefox

Please find below my code of showing responsive image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>xxxxx</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">        
        <img src="http://www.xxxxx.com/images/Events/xxxxx.png" alt="xxxxx" />
    </td>
  </tr>  
</table>-->
<div>
    <img src="http://www.xxxxx.com/images/Events/xxxxx.png" alt="xxxxx" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code for responsive image works fine on `iphone` but when I open the page on `android` the image displays with a scrollbar on `chrome`. On `firefox` it works fine.

**Update**
The page works fine on `firefox` in responsive design view on desktop. It works fine on `iphone`. But it does not work as responsive as it's expected on `android` phone. On `android` phone, it shows scrollbars in browser and in email application as well.

**How do I make image responsive so that it works on `iphone`, `android`, `chrome`, `firefox` and in an email as well ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been fiddling with chrome, firefox and a custom browser on Android and with FF and chrome on a 24" screen on Windows 7 and they all show scrollbars.

Depending on the width and height of your image (actually its ratio: 3:2, 4:3, 16:9, 16:10 etc.) you will see scrollbars when resizing it on a screen with a different ratio than your image. I am not sure, but it may well be that the internal browser engines of FF and Chrome use the same kind of logic to handle image sizing (hense the same effect on Android's Webview and WebChromeClient views) and iOS does not.

You should ask yourself if it is worth all the trouble getting this issue worked out for you or simply accept it as it is (I'd opt for the last).

Have a look at the code below (download => **[Github renevanderlende/stackoverflow](https://github.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow)**) It is not only an acceptable solution for your issue, but also adds some easy to understand Responsiveness to your page you can fiddle with!

The images in the code are from amazing **[Unsplash](http://unsplash.com)**, a fantastic place to find high-quality public domain photos.

And if you are a beginner like me, a visit to **[Codrops](http://tympanus.com/codrops/)** really is a must. Great clear and free tutorials with awesome, ready to use code!!

Cheers, Rene

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <title>question-26464777</title>
 
 <style>
  div { background-size: cover; }   /* fully cover a DIV background */
  img { width: 100%; }    /* Maximize IMG width (height will scale) */
  
  /* Sample media query for responsive design, Resize your browser
     to see the effect. DO check http://chrisnager.github.io/ungrid */
  @media ( min-width :30em) {
   .row { width: 100%; display: table; table-layout: fixed }
   .col { display: table-cell }
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="image 1"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="image 2"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="image 4"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/5.jpg" alt="image 5"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="image 6"></div>
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/8.jpg" alt="image 8"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/renevanderlende/stackoverflow/master/img/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="image 4"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

MAybe you should give a CSS code...

try it:

```
@media screen.... {
img {
max-width:100%;
}
}
```

Or you have overflowed any parent element

Comment: tried it with `@media` queries but still it's not working - @Mego

Answer (score 0):

You have bigger the parent elements I think... 
One of parent elements are bigger that phone display...check it

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;


}
 img, div {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```